# AngularJS (1.6) ng-click function isn't working

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm sure I'm calling it wrong, but I've been working on an interface I'm building with Angular 1.6.

Everything else is working fine, but this ng-click directive. The relevant part of my controller, called signupController with an alias as "sup" is here:

```
  sup.postForm = function($http){
    console.log("postform has been fired.");
     $http.post('api/submit', sup.contactInfo)
      .then(function(response){
        sup.messages.push('Successfully added. Thanks, ' + contactInfo.firstName);
  }, function(response){
        sup.messages.push('Sorry, this failed. Please try again. \n' + response );
  });
}
```

and in my Html, I'm tying the function to a button like so:

```
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" ng-click="postForm">Submit</button>
```

but it's not firing the function. Am I calling it wrong? If so, How to do so properly.

Comment: Should be `ng-click="postForm()"`

Comment: Yes, it should be `ng-click="sup.postForm()"` or ng-submit="sup.postForm()" would make more sense

Comment: `$http` isn't a function parameter, it's a dependency injected into your controller, it holds a scope higher than your function. If it's not in a controller, you're not passing it in.

Answer (score 1):

You function should be `sup.postForm = function(){....}`

And you should inject $http in the controller/directive

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
    controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    // ...
});
```

Then you should make call in your html as

```
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" ng-click="postForm()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I believe if the controller is aliased as `sup`, the ng-click directive also needs to have it aliased `ng-click="sup.postForm()"`

Comment: That's also assuming that `sup = $scope` aliased, we don't know for sure, but if it's true Tah is right

Comment: That is right. I might have missed the alias part. thanks guys.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I think that may be the trick! for Archer, $scope is in the controller, but not really used.